# Identity for the boundary of an open set with boundary in a Hilbert space

Tags: general-topology, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space, $x\in H$ with $\left\|x\right\|_H=1$, $\alpha\in\mathbb R$ and \begin{align}\mathbb H_{x,\:\alpha}&:=\left\{y\in H:\langle x,y\rangle_H\ge\alpha\right\},\\\mathbb H_{x,\:\alpha}^\circ&:=\left\{y\in H:\langle x,y\rangle_H>\alpha\right\}.\end{align} If $U\subseteq\mathbb H_{x,\:\alpha}$, then $$\partial U:=U\setminus\mathbb H_{x,\:\alpha}^\circ.$$

> Let $U$ be an open subset (in the subspace topology) of $\mathbb H_{x,\:\alpha}$ and $\operatorname{Int}U$ denote the interior of $U$ in $H$. How can we show that $\partial U=U\setminus\operatorname{Int}U$ and hence $\partial U$ is well-defined, i.e. independent of the choice of $x$ and $\alpha$?

Since $U$ is $\mathbb H_{x,\:\alpha}$-open, $$U=V\cap\mathbb H_{x,\:\alpha}\tag1$$ for some open subset $V$ of $H$. Now, $V\cap\mathbb H_{x,\:\alpha}^\circ$ is $H$-open and hence $$V\cap\mathbb H_{x,\:\alpha}^\circ\subseteq\operatorname{Int}U\tag2.$$ Let $y\in\operatorname{Int}U$. Then the closed ball $\overline B_\varepsilon(y)$ around $y$ with radius $\varepsilon$ is contained in $\operatorname{Int}U$, $$\overline B_\varepsilon(y)\subseteq\operatorname{Int}U\tag3,$$ for some $\varepsilon>0$. In particular, $$z:=y-\varepsilon x\in\operatorname{Int}U\tag4.$$ Since $\operatorname{Int}U\subseteq U\subseteq\mathbb H_{x,\:\alpha}$, $(4)$ implies $$\alpha\le\langle x,z\rangle_H=\langle x,y\rangle_H-\varepsilon<\langle x,y\rangle_H\tag5$$ and hence $$y\in\mathbb H_{x,\:\alpha}^\circ\tag6.$$

> How can we conclude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question consists of two parts:

1. Let $Y:=\mathbb{H}_{x,\alpha}$, then its interior is $$Y^\circ=\{y:\langle x,y\rangle>\alpha\}$$

Proof: Call the RHS set $W$. If $\langle x,y\rangle>\alpha$ then the ball $B_\epsilon(y)$, $\epsilon<\langle x,y\rangle-\alpha$ is entirely within $Y^\circ$, $$\|y-z\|<\epsilon\implies \langle x,z\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle+\langle x,z-y\rangle\ge\langle x,y\rangle-\epsilon>\alpha$$

If $y\in Y$ is such that $\langle x,y\rangle=\alpha$, then any ball $B_\epsilon(y)$ contains points outside $Y$, for example, $z=y-\frac{\epsilon}{2} x$, $$\langle x,z\rangle=\alpha-\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\alpha$$ As $W$ is the largest open set in $Y$, $W=Y^\circ$.

2. $U\setminus Y^\circ=U\setminus U^\circ$, given that $U$ is open in $Y$ (meaning $U=V\cap Y$ for some $V$ open in $H$). This part is entirely topological in character.

Since $U\subseteq Y$, then $U^{\circ c}\supseteq Y^{\circ c}$, so $U\setminus Y^{\circ}\subseteq U\setminus U^{\circ}$.

Conversely, $U\cap U^{\circ c}\subseteq Y^{\circ c}$ since $U^\circ=(V\cap Y)^\circ=V\cap Y^\circ$.

Comment: (a) $\mathbb H_{x,\:\alpha}$ is defined in terms of an inner product. So, it's not clear to me what you want to tell me with your first sentence. Could you explain what you mean? (b) What is $H_\alpha$ in your answer? (c) In your second paragraph, you mean that $\mathbb H_{x,\:\alpha}^\circ$ is the actual interior of $\mathbb H_{x,\:\alpha}$ in $H$ and I don't need to explicitly define it that way, right?

Comment: The proof does not require any concepts from Hilbert spaces, except to show that $H_\alpha(:=\mathbb{H}_{x,\alpha})$ has interior $Y^\circ$. I presume that that is not the main intent of the question, hence the comment. (c) I use $Y^\circ$ for the interior of $Y$ in $H$. I do not introduce Int because it can be confusing.

Comment: You are right. My problem was that the reference I've consulted explicitly defined $\mathbb H_{x,\:\alpha}^\circ$ as in the quesiton which let me think that it's *not* the actual topological interior of $\mathbb H_{x,\:\alpha}$. But if that's the case, as you wrote, everything boils down to showing that $A\setminus B^\circ=A\setminus A^\circ$ for every topological space, $(E,\tau)$, $B\subseteq E$ and $A\in\left.\tau\right|_B$.

Comment: However, a few remarks: (a) Your argument why $\mathbb H_{x,\:\alpha}^\circ$ is the topological interior is not totally clear to me. For sure, this set is open, since it is equal to $\langle x,\;\cdot\;\rangle_H^{-1}((-\infty,\alpha))$. But your arguments seems to be that if $y$ is an interior point of $\mathbb H_{x,\:\alpha}$, then *any* neighborhood of $y$ contains a point not in $\mathbb H_{x,\:\alpha}$. However, I don't think that this is correct.

Comment: In general, if $y$ is such an interior point, there is a $\varepsilon>0$ such that the closed ball $\overline B_\varepsilon(y)\subseteq\mathbb H_{x,\:\alpha}$. Now you need to show that this closed ball contains a point not in $\mathbb H_{x,\:\alpha}$. Clearly, the idea should be to use the point $z:=y-\varepsilon x$. But this won't work unless $y$ is "sufficiently near the boundary". What am I missing?

Comment: (BTW: Note that $V$ in your question is not defined. I guess it is supposed to be the $H$-open set with $U=V\cap\mathbb H_{x,\:\alpha}$.)

Comment: The argument you are referring to is for $<y,x>=\alpha$. Also the $ V$ is taken from the question. I'll address your queries tomorrow.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Did the amendments address your queries?

Comment: Yes, thank you. (I wasn't notified that you've edited the question.) Please note that I've got a follow up question on derivatives on the space $\mathbb H_{x,\:\alpha}$: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3781630/47771. Maybe you have an idea for that problem as well.

Comment: So, we can conclude that $\partial U=\{v\in V:\langle x,v\rangle=\alpha\}$, right?